# Callback returning empty array - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, callback

I found these answers, but couldn't figure how to implement:

- [Empty array in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45389726/14597561)
- [Node.js returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54437042/14597561)

---

There is a 'callback' function in `app.post` at the bottom of the code.
It is supposed to return the array created in `httpsYtGetFunc`.
It returns the array with `null` value. Rest of the array is empty.

**app.js**

```js
// Declaring variables for the function 'httpsYtGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtGetFunc = "";
let resultOfYtGetFunc = "";
let extractedResultOfYtGetFunc = [];

// This function GETs data, parses it, pushes required values in an array.
function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc, callback) {
  
  apiKey = "AI...MI"
  urlOfYtGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&q=" + queryOfYtGetFunc + "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  // GETting data and storing it in chunks.
  https.get(urlOfYtGetFunc, (response) => {
    const chunks = []
    response.on('data', (d) => {
      chunks.push(d)
    })

    // Parsing the chunks
    response.on('end', () => {
      resultOfYtGetFunc = JSON.parse((Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()))
      // console.log(resultOfYtGetFunc)

      // Extracting useful data, and allocating it.
      for (i = 0; i < (resultOfYtGetFunc.items).length; i++) {
        extractedResultOfYtGetFunc.push(resultOfYtGetFunc.items[i].id.videoId);
        // console.log(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
      }
    })
  })
  callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
}

// Client makes POST request.
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  query = "niall";

  // The callback
  ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query, (ytQueryAppJs) => {
    console.log("ytQueryAppJs:");
    console.log(ytQueryAppJs);
  });
});
```

The console logs only `null`.

I believe that `callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);` is running before `https.get` finishes.

**Could somebody please suggest how to fix it and log all the results?**

Thank you so much.

---

This is the link to original question:

[How to synchronize 'time-consuming value allotment' of a variable, with the next commands, in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67757075/14597561)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for looking it up. I have tried the method "2. Restructure Code" of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/14597561) in the question above. I'm sharing the problem that I faced while implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.on('end', ()` associate a function to the "end" event of `https.get` method. When you call `callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);` outside of the `https.get()` block, the https request has not been finish yet, and the `extractedResultOfYtGetFunc` array is empty.

You need to move the callback function to the `response.on('end')` block

```
function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc, callback) {
  apiKey = "AI...MI"
  urlOfYtGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&q=" + queryOfYtGetFunc + "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  // GETting data and storing it in chunks.
  https.get(urlOfYtGetFunc, (response) => {
    const chunks = []
    response.on('data', (d) => {
      chunks.push(d)
    })

    // Parsing the chunks
    response.on('end', () => {
      resultOfYtGetFunc = JSON.parse((Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()))
      // console.log(resultOfYtGetFunc)

      // Extracting useful data, and allocating it.
      for (i = 0; i < (resultOfYtGetFunc.items).length; i++) {
        extractedResultOfYtGetFunc.push(resultOfYtGetFunc.items[i].id.videoId);
        // console.log(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
      }

      callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc); // move the callback here
    })  
  })
  // callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You will need to add 1 more parameter in the callback function to receive the error, if any.
`ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query, (err, ytQueryAppJs) => {`

Comment: This seems to solve the issue. I do not know why but I'm returned with `TypeError: Cannot set property 'length' of undefined`. I checked, and the API quota limit has not exceeded. (I can't verify if this has, indeed, solved the issue.)

Comment: Thank you so much, pal. I had some unnecessary code 'uncommented', which was causing the issue. On a side note, could you please elaborate how do we use `response.on('error')`?

Comment: I read the document [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback), the `response.on('error')` is used to handle error when you send the request and cannot receive the desired response. For example, when you received error 404. It makes the code more reliable

Comment: Update: I had to remove the `null` argument to make it work.

Comment: Oh, alright. `.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});` This is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Ah, I noticed that you declare only 1 parameter in the callback `ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query, (ytQueryAppJs) => {` If you change to `ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query, (err, ytQueryAppJs) => {` you won't need to remove the 'null' argument

Comment: Yes, it did work. Could you please explain this syntax?

Comment: When you call the callback function, you're passing 2 parameters `callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);`. So when you declare the function, you need 2 parameters :)

Comment: Alright. What else can we put instead of `null`? I'm assuming that putting `null` won't log us the error (shall any.)

Comment: the `null` indicates that there is no error. When you encounter an error (in `response.on('error'))` , you need to call the callback like: `callback(error)`, then the caller knows that there is an error.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm not exactly clear with the syntax as on how to implement it. But I get the concept. Thank you so much for sparing your time and educating me. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not Node.js developer but I belive that callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc); need to be called in http.get callback function.

**EDITED** move to `response.on('end'` callback

Something like that:

```
function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc, callback) {
  apiKey = "AI...MI"
  urlOfYtGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&q=" + queryOfYtGetFunc + "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  // GETting data and storing it in chunks.
  https.get(urlOfYtGetFunc, (response) => {
    const chunks = []
    response.on('data', (d) => {
      chunks.push(d)
    })

    // Parsing the chunks
    response.on('end', () => {
      resultOfYtGetFunc = JSON.parse((Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()))
      // console.log(resultOfYtGetFunc)

      // Extracting useful data, and allocating it.
      for (i = 0; i < (resultOfYtGetFunc.items).length; i++) {
        extractedResultOfYtGetFunc.push(resultOfYtGetFunc.items[i].id.videoId);
        // console.log(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
      }
      callback (null, extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing the same. But it didn't work.

Comment: Then try inside response.on('end'... it seems to be called at the end of respons accoriding to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659002/what-does-response-on-mean-node-js) "...The two you have above are response.on('data'...) which is when you get the data and response.on('end'...) is at the end of the response, simple as that!"